# Mixed pollution degree creepage distance

Tags: isolation, clearance, creepage, pollution

Say you need to comply with a creepage distance but you can't do it under a specific pollution degree. I had 2 scenarios where I had mixed pollution degrees:

1. The creepage distance is almost enough under pollution degree 2 (only 0.1 - 0.2 mm short). So I don't need to coat the whole distance. (Easier/faster production)
2. The coating can't be applied all the way across the distance, in order to avoid having coating drops over some exposed pads, so I have to stop the coating shorter than needed. (production constrain)

Is there some kind of formula to make sure that the combination of both creepage distances under different pollution degrees is equivalent to the creepage under one pollution degree or the other?

**Example**:

I need **5 mm** under **pollution degree 2** OR **3 mm** under **pollution degree 1**.

Is there a way to check if a combination like: ***3 mm PD2 + 1 mm PD1*** is ok?

Comment: Tricky question.  Sounds like this is not your first compliance-related project.  Does your company have a relationship with UL or another NTL?  If so, can you bounce this off of them for a quasi-official opinion?

Comment: Does the PCB have two different compartments, one exposed to external air and one not?

Comment: @AnalogKid I can check if can contact them. In the meantime, I'd to have an input from the experts here.

Comment: @winny It's more due to coating application. Some parts are coated, some not

Comment: Is coating everything an option?

Comment: @winny For the 2nd scenario, it's difficult. We don't want to have coating on some exposed pads, we have to stop coating further away. We need to keep these pads exposed because they'll be used later

Comment: Depending on coating used, masking off those areas with tape could be an option. I have used it in the past.

Comment: @winny Yes. That introduces an additional production step. That's not the best solution for high volumes. This why I'm thinking of a combined creepage distance to make this faster (and maybe cheaper)

Comment: A valid concern. Make a bare PCB, coat the part you can coat and set up or send out for a tracking test?